# Rational points on a circle with centre $(\pi, e)$

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

A circle is centred at $(\pi,e)$. What is the maximum no. of rational points it can have?
(A rational point is one with both coordinates rational).
1 rational point is definitely possible, just choose any rational point, and alter the radius to get it through. My book says that only one rational point is possible, as $\pi\neq qe\quad q\in Q$. That's their whole explanation. I don't understand how that's enough.
**Edit:**
 It has been pointed out that the problem is equivalent to showing $q_1\pi+q_2e=q_3$ has no non trivial solutions. Is this known to be true? Can someone prove it in an elementary way?

Comment: Need a little more, that $1$, $\pi$, $e$ are linearly independent over the rationals. And it is non-obvious even that $\pi\ne qe$.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/832636/65389)'s a better answer.

Comment: $(\pi,\sqrt[3]2)$ would be way easier ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay I got it, suppose it passes through (a,b).
Then the equation of circle is $x^2-a^2+y^2-b^2-2\pi( x-a)-2e(y-b)=0$ If x and y are both rational then $q_1\pi+q_2e=q_3$ with not everything 0 .I still have to prove  this  impossible. I  don't think it's equivalent to $\pi \neq qe$.
**Edit:** As has been pointed out to me, two rational points are not possible if $\pi $ and $ e$ are linearly independent over the rationals, and this is still an open problem

Comment: The problem is that this is [not known to be impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence#Algebraic_independence_of_known_constants).

Comment: We don't need algebraic independence, just linear independence in this problem, right? Is that proven?

Comment: Your book is wrong : there are several rational points on the circle centered on $(\sqrt 2, 1+\sqrt 2)$ and radius $\sqrt2$ (for example, $(0,1+ \sqrt 2)$ and $(\sqrt 2,1)$), even though $\sqrt 2 / (1+ \sqrt 2) \notin \Bbb Q$

Comment: $(\sqrt{2},1)$ isn't a rational point by my definition. Though I admit the book is not to be trusted.

Comment: oh lol how did I manage to write something this wrong XD.

Comment: ok, for any rational point $(a,b)$, the rational point $(b-1,a+1)$ is at the same distance from $(\sqrt 2, 1+ \sqrt 2)$, so they both are on the same circle.

Comment: Yes, but that is because  the two coordinates for the centre are linearly dependent. How do we show that that isn't the case for $(\pi,e)$?

Comment: I was merely pointing out that the argument given by the book is incorrect, so that you stop wondering about it. As you showed, the true reason is that $1, \pi, e$ are linearly independant over $\Bbb Q$. I am not aware if this is a known result.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll change the question to that.

Comment: If you followed the link I provided, you would see that it is not even known whether $e+\pi$ is rational.

Comment: @Harald Thanks. I followed the link but I think I didn't read that sentence. How do I end this question then?

Comment: I suggest you write your own answer based on the discussion here and what you have learned, and then accept it. This way the question won't hang around forever in an unanswered state.